# Diagonal morphism of regular variety is a regular embedding

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $X$ be a regular $k-$variety (i.e. all of its local rings are regular) of pure dimension $d$. Then I would like to show that the diagonal morphism $X\rightarrow X\times_k X$ is a regular embedding of codimension $d$, to be able to prove exercise $12.2.M$ in Ravi Vakil's "Foundations of Algebraic Geometry".

The preceding exercise shows that any closed embedding $Y \rightarrow Z$ with $Y$ regular and $Z$ regular at all points in the image of $Y$ is a regular embedding. I'd like to use this (particularly because Vakil lists $12.2.M$ as a consequence of the preceding exercise), only I'm having trouble proving that $X \times_k X$ is regular at points on the diagonal. Thus what I would really like to know is:

> Let $X$ be a regular $k-$variety. Then $X \times_k X$ is regular at points on the diagonal.

Since $X$ is finite type, I can explicitly describe the local rings of $X$ as quotients of local rings of affine space, and use the kernels involved to explicitly describe the local rings of $X \times_k X$ as quotients of the local rings of $X$, but I can't then do very much with this, and I'm not sure that this is even the right approach.

**Edit:** Some of the answers suggest that regularity is not enough to show that the diagonal is a regular embedding. One provides an example of a regular scheme $W$ where $W \times W$ isn't regular at the diagonal, so the approach taken in this question is certainly flawed.

Comment: Interesting. It's very doable if $X$ is _smooth_ but that's not quite the same.

Comment: @Hoot Ah, proving smoothness translates over would be easier, because you could explicitly compute the Jacobian of $X \times_k X$ as just two copies of the Jacobian of $X$ in a block diagonal matrix (I think), but you're right that it's not the same (and I wouldn't know how to prove that this implied the embedding was regular). For what it's worth, smoothness was the condition I found this theorem usually stated with (e.g. in Fulton's intersection theory) although I couldn't find a proof for that case either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without some hypothesis on $k$ I don't think it's true that the diagonal embedding $X \to X \times_k X$ is regular. Like take everybody's favorite regular but non-smooth scheme over the non-perfect field $k:= \Bbb{F}_p(t)$. Namely, the scheme $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb{F}_p(t)[x]/(x^p - t)$. We first compute the tensor product

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \Bbb{F}_p(t)[x]/(x^p - t) \otimes_{\Bbb{F}_p(t)} \Bbb{F}_p(t)[y]/(y^p - t) &\cong& \Bbb{F}_p(t)[x,y]/(x^p - t, y^p - t) \\ 
&\cong& L[y]/(y-\alpha)^p \end{eqnarray*}$$
where $L := \Bbb{F}_p(t)[x]/(x^p-t)$ and $\alpha$ is the image of $x$ in $L$.

We see that the tensor product is a local non-reduced  of dimension $0$. Hence the diagonal $X \to X \times_k X$ is a map from a point to a fat point and so is not regular.

**Edit:** Ravi told me via email that there is indeed an error in the notes with regards to this question.

Comment: I think you want to say $x - y$. Anyway, this is great. Sort of disturbing that his varieties aren't closed under product but oh well. I wonder if demanding that they be geometrically reduced patches things up?

Comment: @Ben To clarify, we're not looking for regularity, we're looking for regularity at points on the diagonal, in this case that's a single point. Thus the non-reducedness doesn't a priori imply that it's not regular at the diagonal. However, this scheme is NOT regular at the diagonal (the point $P$ corresponding to the prime $(X-Y, X^p-t, Y^p-t)$). Since $(0) \lneq (X^p-t) \lneq (X-Y, X^p-t, Y^p-t)$ is a maximal chain of primes in $\mathcal{A}^2_k$, $P$ is minimal and so the local ring at $P$ is $0-$dimensional. [continued below]

Comment: However, the tangent space to $X \times X$ at $P$ is cut out from the tangent space to $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ at $P$ by the equations $X^p-t, Y^p-t \mod{P_P}^2$. But since these are the same $\mod{P_P}^2$, the tangent space to $X \times X$ at $P$ is one dimensional, so the local ring is in fact, not regular. We could certainly have used that $(X-Y)^p = 0$ is still true in the local ring, but it's not immediately clear to my why $(X-Y) \not= 0$ in the stalk (I'm wary of explicit computations with elements in localisations of non-integral domains).

Comment: Anyway, if you'd update your answer to reflect the comments above, I'd be happy to accept it since this shows that this is actually a counter example to the question as posed.

Comment: @TomOldfield I think his ring only has one prime, so it's already local as written. Maybe it's easier to see this if you view it like this: $L = \mathbb F_p(t)[x]/(x^p - t)$ is a field. Let $\alpha$ be the image of $x$ in $L$. Now I form $L[y]/(y - \alpha)^p$.

Comment: My point, I think, is that you don't need to do any explicit computations with the tangent space (although that's fun too). Just the fact that regular local rings are domains. Someone should probably tell Ravi (after checking everything a bunch of times).

Comment: @Hoot Ah, that's a lot better, thanks! I forgot $L$ was a field, it's been a while since I properly thought about characteristic $p$. Yeah, once you know it's a local ring (and indeed, a $0-$dimensional one), the local ring at the maximal ideal is just the ring itself, which is not reduced and so not regular.

I'm going to send Vakil an e-mail in the next few days, about this and another potential error in the same chapter (I was waiting for some clarity on this and to check the other error before sending it).

Comment: I usually leave comments on his blog so others can see.

Comment: @Hoot Good idea, I'll probably do that then.

Comment: @TomOldfield I edited my answer. Btw I think Ravi is at a conference right now; he hasn't replied any of my emails lately.

Comment: @Hoot I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a flat locally noetherian scheme over $S$ (and in particular in your case), it is (formally) smooth over $S$ if and only if the diagonal is a regular embedding. So you are trying to prove that your variety is smooth over $k$. This is true for instance if $k$ is algebraically closed or of characteristic zero, but not in general.

For a proof of the first claim, see Bourbaki, Algèbre Commutative chap. 10, §
7 n. 10 Théorème 4, (i) ⟺ (v). As in most of this section of that book, there are some finiteness hypotheses on the morphisms, but they are not necessary if instead of "smoothness" you want to obtain "formal smoothness for the discrete (and so for any other) topology" (though the proof without them is more dificult). If you are interested in the proof in general I can sketch one here, but using deep homological methods.

For "regular does not imply smooth" you have examples in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrically_regular_ring

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you be able to provide a proof of the fact you've mentioned, or at least a reference? I've seen it claimed several times that smooth implies that the diagonal is a regular embedding, but not the converse (and I haven't seen a proof either way).

Comment: @Tom I have edited the answer answering to that.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but unfortunately I don't have access to that. Moreover I don't know what formally smooth means, or how it relates to smoothness, so the diagonal being regular being equivalent to the formal smoothness doesn't show that this theorem fails (since it might, perhaps be true that regular implies formal smoothness). Could you maybe clarify exactly what you're claiming? (i.e., for a k variety $W$, the diagonal is a regular embedding iff it $W$ is formally smooth and there exist regular, but not formally smooth $k-$ varieties)

Comment: I'm sorry I do not know any other reference. It should be also somewhere in EGA IV, but I am not able to find it. Smooth = formally smooth (for any topology) + morphism of finite type, so if your variety is of finite type (as usual in most books), smooth = formally smooth = regular diagonal.

Comment: And in general, formally smooth is equivalent to geometric regularity (you can find this in EGA 0$_{IV}$, both Matsumura's, etc.), so regular does not imply formal smoothness (same link as in the answer).

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks. I'll have a dig around and see if I can make sense of this, I'll let you know once I understand the problem a little better.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to a question in Hoot's comments (I'm sorry not been able to post it as a comment by lack of reputation): "I wonder if demanding that they be geometrically reduced patches things up?"

No, $X\times_kX$ is regular (if and) only if $X$ is smooth over $k$. More generally, if $A$ is a noetherian ring, $B$ a local flat $A$-algebra such that $B\otimes_AB$ is regular, then $B$ is an essentially of finite type smooth $A$-algebra. The finiteness condition follows from [Corollaire (3.6) in Ferrand, Monomorphismes et morphismes absolument plats](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/BSMF/BSMF_1972__100_/BSMF_1972__100__97_0/BSMF_1972__100__97_0.pdf). An then, for the smoothness, if $B\otimes_AB$ is regular, then $B$ is regular since it is a retract, and therefore the surjective map $B\otimes_AB \to B$ is a closed regular embedding. We apply now Bourbaki, Algèbre Commutative chap. 10, § 7 n. 10 Théorème 4, (i) ⟺ (v).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/643134)

Comment: This was useful to me; thank you.

Comment: @Emily I would like to have posted it as a comment, but not because it does not answer the question. In fact, this answer shows more: that there is no necessity of an explicit new example, any example of regular but not smooth gives an example of $X\times_kX$ not regular (though maybe regular at the diagonal) with $X$ regular.

Comment: In such a case, it is perfectly acceptable to pose and answer your own question; that way, the corpus of knowledge is more comprehensive and organized :)

Comment: @emily, while that is generally so, in this case A.G.'s answer is more useful and to the point here than anywhere else.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Fair enough, although I find it a bit out of sync with the typical flow.

Comment: The "typical flow" is very nuch at odds, from time to time, with the way math questions are dealt with in the real world.

Answer (score -1):

Sadly I cannot comment. In any case:

(1) make clear what $k$ is (*any* field?) It depends greatly on the properties of $k$, as was already mentioned by A.G.

(2) unlike what some people think, there is no standard definition of "variety". E.g. everyone assumes *of finite type" (I think), but some assume irreducible, geometrically integral, whatever. For that reason you should always state what you mean by it.

(3) Over any field "smoothness" is equivalent to geometric regularity (see EGA IV), and thus "smoothness" is equivalent to regularity over a *perfect* field.

(4) The notion of smoothness is superior to regularity, exactly because it behaves very well with respect to base change. Over nonperfect fields I think regularity is less interesting.

Comment: $1)$ As best I can tell, $k$ is indeed allowed to be any field. $2)$ For me, a variety is a reduced, separated, finite type $k-$scheme. With regards to $3$ and $4$, I am aware that smoothness is the more useful and better behaved condition and that smoothness implies regularity, whereas regularity only implies smoothness for finite type $k-$schemes when $k$ is perfect. Are you agreeing with A.G that the diagonal being a regular embedding is equivalent to some sort of smoothness, and therefore that the problem as stated is incorrect?